# High Response to Server

Tags: gtmetrix

I have been searching for the reason why the Response to Server (TTFB) has some major delays on:

https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/cu9yoV/https://graphic-cv.com

without finding the real reason. It resides on a shared server which in fact is running with good hardware and the site is running PHP 7.1, APCu cache, Cloudflare, PrestaShop 1.6.1.18 platform configured with the best speed optimization setting in the backend

As seen on the metrix test the site requests are loading within seconds, but the first http/https request to the server can delay the site all from 3 seconds to 20 seconds. If I do a re-test it will go down to 2-5 seconds, but if I haven't accessed the site 30 min and up, issues will arise again with high load time.

How do I find the culprit which is delaying the TTFB? The hosting company with all their resources for testing/monitoring haven't provided me with a clear answer.

Comment: How do you expect us to answer this?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd it's not normal for it to be delayed for 20 seconds. I'm not asking why its waiting time is 5-6 seconds, when in fact it should be under 500ms. How can I troubleshoot it to come up with a better understanding what is causing it?

Comment: Sounds like a cache being prepared on first request and being cleared when not used in 30 minutes. The only way to know is by measuring all individual steps.

Comment: Which cache are we suspecting? A cron job hits the HTML HOME PAGE once every hour. But APCu holds it for just a couple of minutes, not even the 30 min as I indicated. Still the first request is 15kb, and as seen all other CSS, JS, images are cached in Cloudflare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was hardware related. After the hosting company upgraded their hardware, new CPUs, RAID-10, DDR4, Litespeed, now my site loads within 3 seconds.